# How to access props in react native for Image's source uri?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Basically, to declare image source uri in Image, then we will do something like this:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'welcome_notes' }} style={style.cardPicture} />
```

The question is how to access props in the uri?

I tried the following:

```
<Image source={{uri: '{this.props.imageSource}' }} style={style.cardPicture} />
```

Didn't work. I have tried several others too, but somehow couldn't manage to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more straightforward than I thought. It turns out just write the props directly without curly braces or anything.

That is,

```
<Image source={{uri: this.props.imageSource }} style={style.cardPicture} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use directly the props

```
<Image source={{uri: this.props.imageSource }} style={style.cardPicture} />
```

as 'this.props.imageSource' will create a string with value this.props.imageSource